# Is it possible to add your own strings to a Django SearchVectorField?

Tags: django, postgresql, full-text-search

I know how to do this with raw PostgreSQL commands, but want to know if there is a way to do this with Django PostgreSQL search.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    search_vector = SearchVectorField(blank=True)

def update_search(person):
    vector = SearchVector('name') + SearchVector('description')
    if person.active:
        vector = vector + SearchVector('alive')
    person.search_vector = vector
```

> django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'alive' into field.

I tried making 'alive' a @property method, but it looks like it only wants a db field for search.

Is there a way to do this in pure Django ORM or should I go the raw SQL route?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [Value() expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#value-expressions) to add a string to in your [SearchVector](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#searchvector) as in below example:

```
from django.db.models import Value

    ...
    vector = vector + SearchVector(Value('alive'))
    ...
```

Comment: Ooooh. Nice find. Will try this.

Comment: On Django 3, I had to specify the output_type: `Value('alive', output_field=models.CharField())`

Comment: Used this as a starting point to keep a SearchVectorField updated in a model save() method. The problem was to use a value from a foreignkey of the model itself (the fk is `category` in this example), because `SearchVector('category__name')` gave an error on Postgres. This approach worked:

`SearchVector('title') + SearchVector(Value(self.category.name, output_field=models.CharField()))`

Answer (score -1):

`SearchVector` should not be used like this. It should be ONLY accept field name.

Please look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/search/)

Comment: Actually `SearchVectori` accept other than field names.
You can use expressions in `SearchVector` as I've wrote in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47497078/755343).