# Is it possible to persist a joined field in Djangos SearchVectorField?

Tags: django, postgresql, full-text-search

Is it possible to persist a joined field with Djangos SearchVectorField for full text search?

For example:

```
class P(models.Model):
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    search_vector = SearchVectorField(null=True, blank=True)
```

code:

```
p = P.objects.get(id=1)
p.search_vector = SearchVector('brand__name')
p.save()
```

raises this exception:

```
FieldError: Joined field references are not permitted in this query
```

If this is not possible how can you increase the performance of joined annotated queries?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a workaround to your issue:

```
p = P.objects.annotate(brand_name=SearchVector('brand__name')).get(id=1)
p.search_vector = p.brand_name
p.save()
```

**Update 2023-11-23**

As reported in official [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#update):

> If you’re just updating a record and don’t need to do anything with the model object, the most efficient approach is to call update(), rather than loading the model object into memory.
>
> Using update() also prevents a race condition wherein something might change in your database in the short period of time between loading the object and calling save().
>
> Finally, realize that update() does an update at the SQL level and, thus, does not call any save() methods on your models, nor does it emit the pre_save or post_save signals (which are a consequence of calling Model.save()).

So in this case you can use this query to perform a single SQL query on the database:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVector
from django.db.models import F

P.objects.annotate(
    brand_name=SearchVector('brand__name')
).filter(
    id=1
).update(
    search_vector=F('brand_name')
)
```

Or a shorter form (suggested by @christophe31) is:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVector

P.objects.filter(id=1).update(search_vector=SearchVector('brand__name))
```

Both above solutions generate the same SQL code in the database.

Comment: aren't you making a redundant db query with that `.get(id=1)`? I'm also looking for a solution to build a search vector from a foreign relationship.

Comment: @Nad I've updated my answer with a solution that perform one query only on db, but read the documentation about the difference between save and update

Comment: thanks for this. My issue is I already have an instance of an model and for which I want to update the search_vector from a post_save signal. I posted a question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51105651/django-postgres-searchvectorfield-from-foreign-key

Comment: found an answer of yours to this here! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42679743/is-it-possible-to-add-your-own-strings-to-a-django-searchvectorfield/47497078#47497078  
Brilliant, thank you

Comment: @nad I'm you've found an useful answer for your problem. If it works please vote for it.

Comment: ```P.objects.filter(id=1).update(search_vector=SearchVector("brand__name"))``` is enough