# Django: JSONField + Full Text Search + Indexing -> Seq Scan. How to configure indexing to work?

Tags: django, postgresql, indexing, full-text-search

Im using Django 2.2 and PostgreSQL 12.

Here is my model:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVectorField, SearchVector
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField

class ProfileUser(models.Model):
    name = JSONField()

    search_vector = SearchVectorField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            GinIndex(fields=['search_vector'], name='user_full_name_gin_idx')
        ]

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProfileUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        ProfileUser.objects.update(search_vector=SearchVector('name'))
```

Here Im creating a new user and trying to find it:

```
from apps.profiles.models import ProfileUser
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVector

ProfileUser.objects.create(name=[{'name': 'SomeUser', 'lang': 'en'}])
ProfileUser.objects.annotate(search=SearchVector('name')).filter(search__icontains='someuser').explain()
```

Result:

> "Seq Scan on profiles_user  (cost=0.00..81.75 rows=1 width=316)\n 
>   Filter: (upper((to_tsvector(COALESCE((name)::text, ''::text)))::text)
>   ~~ '%someuser%'::text)"

How to make indexing working?

**EDIT:**
As a response to @ivissani's comment, I added 5000 users and tried `.filter(search__icontains='someuser')` and `.filter(search_vector__icontains='someuser')` - same story -> `Seq Scan`

Comment: I think you are searching over the JSONField instead of using `search_vector` because you are doing `annotate(search=SearchVector('name')).filter(search__icontains='someuser')` and I think you should be doing `.filter(search_vector__icontains='someuser')` instead

Comment: Anyway, the database will decided whether using the index is better. If you have only one entry in your table is likely that a full scan is more efficient that an index scan

Comment: @ivissani, hope 5k users enough :) Nothing has changed.

Comment: 5,000 rows is still a fairly tiny amount of data, in relative terms. Two things I try in situations like these: load up several millions rows of data, and grab the raw SQL that Django is running, with something like debug toolbar. Then take the SQL directly into `psql` or PG Admin and tweak to see if you can get it to hit an index. That'll offer provide a clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this article](https://www.thebookofjoel.com/full-text-search-django-postgres) I found short solution for Django 2.2+

Model:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField
from django.contrib.postgres.indexes import GinIndex
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVectorField, SearchVector
from django.db import models


class ProfileUser(models.Model):
    name = JSONField()
    search_vector = SearchVectorField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        indexes = [GinIndex(fields=["search_vector"], name="user_full_name_gin_idx")]

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProfileUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        ProfileUser.objects.filter(pk=self.pk).update(search_vector=SearchVector('name'))
```

Query:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchQuery
from apps.profiles.models import ProfileUser

ProfileUser.objects.create(name=[{'name': 'Adriano Celentano', 'lang': 'en'}])

partial_name = 'celen'  # or 'celentano adr'

query = re.sub(r'[!\'()|&]', ' ', partial_name).strip()
if query:
    query = re.sub(r'\s+', ' & ', query)
    query += ':*'  # -> 'celen:*' or 'celentano & adr:*'

    # Please note, that `search_type` parameter was added to Django 2.2.
    ProfileUser.objects.filter(search_vector=SearchQuery(query, search_type='raw')).explain()
```

Such `SearchQuery` allows to search names partially (ie "starting with" approach, example: can find "celen" but can not find "lent") and case insensitively. If you need to "lent" part, probably you need to use `Trigram Similarity` as shown in @paolo-melchiorre 's [article](https://www.paulox.net/2017/12/22/full-text-search-in-django-with-postgresql/#trigram-similarity)

> "Bitmap Heap Scan on profiles_user  (cost=13.03..194.69 rows=101
>   width=333)\n  Recheck Cond: (search_vector @@
>   to_tsquery('celen:*'::text))\n  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on
>   user_full_name_gin_idx  (cost=0.00..13.01 rows=101 width=0)\n
>
>   Index Cond: (search_vector @@ to_tsquery('celen:*'::text))"

P.S. Regarding `icontains` and `contains` I found in different sources, that they always do `Sequential Scan`.

---

One more possibly useful [article](http://rubyjacket.com/build/django-psql-fts.html).

Answer (score 7):

I think you were not using completely well the full-text search Django module.
The main issue I can see in your code are:

- updating the search vector field without filtering your object
- executing your search query on an annotated `SearchVector` using an `icontains` instead of using the `SearchVectorField` with your `GinIndex`

I updated a bit your models code:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField
from django.contrib.postgres.indexes import GinIndex
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVectorField, SearchVector
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import F


class ProfileUser(models.Model):
    name = JSONField()
    search_vector = SearchVectorField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        indexes = [GinIndex(fields=["search_vector"], name="user_full_name_gin_idx")]

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        ProfileUser.objects.annotate(search_vector_name=SearchVector("name")).filter(
            id=self.id
        ).update(search_vector=F("search_vector_name"))
```

As you can see I added an annotate and a filter in `save` method to update only the search vector fields of your model (You can find in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46000563/755343) of mine another example of this usage)

Here you can see the code I used in the python shell to create a new `ProfileUser`.
You can see the two SQL query executed in the `save` method:

```
>>> from users.models import ProfileUser
>>> ProfileUser.objects.create(name=[{'name': 'SomeUser', 'lang': 'en'}])

INSERT INTO "users_profileuser" ("name", "search_vector")
VALUES ('[{"name": "SomeUser", "lang": "en"}]', NULL) RETURNING "users_profileuser"."id"

UPDATE "users_profileuser"
SET "search_vector" = to_tsvector(COALESCE(("users_profileuser"."name")::text, ''))
WHERE "users_profileuser"."id" = 1
```

And below there the code I executed in the python shell to search the `ProfileUser` with the `SearchVectorField` using the `GINindex` of the model.
You can see the `Index Scan` on the index:

```
>>> from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchQuery
>>> ProfileUser.objects.filter(search_vector=SearchQuery('someuser')).explain()

EXPLAIN
SELECT "users_profileuser"."id",
    "users_profileuser"."name",
    "users_profileuser"."search_vector"
FROM "users_profileuser"
WHERE "users_profileuser"."search_vector" @@ (plainto_tsquery('someuser')) = true

"Bitmap Heap Scan on users_profileuser  (cost=12.28..21.74 rows=4 width=68)
    Recheck Cond: (search_vector @@ plainto_tsquery('someuser'::text))
    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on user_full_name_gin_idx  (cost=0.00..12.28 rows=4 width=0)
            Index Cond: (search_vector @@ plainto_tsquery('someuser'::text))"
```

If you want to know more about [Full-text Search with Django and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/full-text-search+django+postgresql) you can read the official documentation about the [full-text search](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/postgres/search/).

If you are interested in external article about that here it's the one I wrote:
[Full-Text Search in Django with PostgreSQL](https://www.paulox.net/2017/12/22/full-text-search-in-django-with-postgresql/)